# Splitting into sentences Java

Tags: java, regex

I want to split a text into sentences. My text contains `\n` character in between. I want the splitting to be done at `\n` and `.`(dot). I cannot use `BreakIterator` as splitting condition for it is a space followed by a period (In the text I want to split, that isn't necessary).

**Example**:

```
i am a java programmer.i like coding in java. pi is 3.14\n regex not working
```

Should output:

```
['i am a java programmer', 'i like coding in java', 'pi is 3.14', 'regex not working']
```

I tried a simple regex which splits on either `\n` or `.`:

```
[\\\\n\\.]
```

This isn't working although, specifying separately works.

```
\\\\n
\\.
```

So can anyone give a regex that will split on either `\n` or `.` ?

Another problem is I don't want splitting to be done in case of decimals like *5.6*.

Comment: What if you have something like "blah blah U.S.". Do you want to consider it as one sentence or two sentences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `string.split("[\n.]")` to split at `\n` or `.`

Inside character class, `.` has no special meaning. So there is no need for escaping `.`

**Edit:** `string.split("\n|[.](?<!\\d)(?!\\d)")` avoids splitting of decimal numbers.

Here, for each `.` a lookbehind and a lookahead is there to check whether there is a digit on both sides. If both are not numbers, split is applied.

`\n|\\.(?!\\d)|(?<!\\d)\\.` avoids split for `.` with digits on both sides.

`\n|(?<!\\d)[.](?!\\d)` avoids split if any side has a digit

So **what you require might be**

```
string.split("\n|\\.(?!\\d)|(?<!\\d)\\.")
```

which splits `something.4` but not `3.14`

Comment: that would also split '5.6'

Comment: @user1523170 did you use the same regex or avoided any escapes?

Comment: @user1523170 check the third one

Comment: @user1523170 each suits some context. select the one suited for yours.

Comment: i want 'something.4' to split. '3.4' to not split. 'something 4.something' to split. the first RE doesn't work for 'something.4' case

Comment: and now shall the downvote be reverted? or may i know the reason for the downvote?

Comment: Fyi Your last regex will still split 3.14

Comment: @Bohemian at least not in `java`. pls check it.

Answer (score 9):

This java regex should go it:

```
"\n|((?<!\\d)\\.(?!\\d))"
```

Points here:

- you don't need to escape `\n`, ever
- those weird looking things around the dot are negative look arounds, and means "the previous/next character must not be a digit

This regex says: "either a newline, or a literal dot that is not preceded or followed by a digit

FYI, you don't need to escape characters in a character class (between []) except for the brackets themselves.

Comment: @Bohemian what about **some text.5 items of something**

Comment: @naveedS added negative look behind to require non digits both before and after a dot. Note though that regex would struggle to distinguish a decimal as in the question from this unhappy coincidence of two sentences: `I have 3.6 shooters are best.`

Comment: @Bohemian still doesn't split if digit is there on **any** side of the decimal point. so same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need not double-escape stuff in a Java regex in the `[]` block:

```
[.\n]
```

should work.